# private dns name enable with 2 vpc ecr dkr endpoints results in error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecr

i am trying to create 2 separate vpc endpoints for ecr dkr for 2 different subnet zones in same region. Now the aws documentation says i need to enable the private dns for the vpc endpoints but when i do that i can only create 1 vpc endpoint . while creating the other , the error comes -

"private-dns-enabled cannot be set because there is already a conflicting DNS domain for *.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com in the VPC vpc-01dce1584dbff2s28".

what can be the workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any workaround for that, as it would require creating **two identical record sets** in private hosted zone associated with your VPC, which off course is not possible.

Thus, if you really need two independent interface endpoint for `dkr.ecr`, then one can have private dns option enabled, while the second one will have to have it **disabled**.

This means that your application which requires using the second interface endpoint will have to **explicitly** specify it for every AWS API operation.

Comment: thanks for the update .. i didnt create a private hosted zone . I just ticked the enable private dns while creating the interface endpoint. And the private dns name was being displayed as - *.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com . please let me know if i can populate the private DNS name field by creating the record set if it is possible.